# preg_match on formula and characters given?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to be able to tell if there is a match of serials given the following:

```
$formula = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX';
$chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
$serials = array(
    '9876-345-ABC',
    '7856Y-YURYW-00UEW-YUI23-YYYYY',
    '0934Y-R6834-27495-89999-11123'
);
```

So, given the following `$serials` array, how to return true for all values matching any of the characters in `$chars` using the specified formula, where `X` is a placeholder for any character inside of `$chars`.  But I also need to make sure the hyphens in the formula are in the right place in the value of the serials given.

```
foreach($serials as $serial)
{
    if(preg_match("???", $serial) === 0)
        echo 'found';
}
```

Should echo found on the last 2 elements of `$serials`.  Seems simple enough, but I still can't wrap my head around regexes no matter how hard I try.

Comment: This is a quite simple regex... you should type "regex example" in google, and find plenty of examples doing this...

Comment: `^([A-Z0-9]{5}-){4}[A-Z0-9]{5}$`

Comment: I need to plugin `$formula` directly as is and `$chars` directly as is into the `preg_match`, how?  `$formula` and `$chars` are user-defined variables.  Can be anything really.

Comment: You could try at least something. As a hint: you can create a character class from the `$chars` and replace each `X` with that char class. And use that regex to `preg_grep` the 2 values. At least that.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking, I have tried different approaches, but am thinking this is more efficient using `preg_match`, if I only knew how to use it in this sense.

Comment: But what if the formula is this:  `XXX-XX-XXX-X-XXXXX`?  Can't use those numbers formats.

Comment: Ok, and about these?  `XX-XX`, `XXX-X-XX`, `XXX-XXX-X`, `X-X-X`  The formulas are user defined and can be changed to anything.

Comment: What do you exactly want to match??In your example you say that you do not want to match `9876-345-ABC`

Comment: I need to match the pattern value of whatever `$formula` is, and `$formula` can be anything.  But `$formula` is always using `X` chars as a placeholder and hyphens `-` as separators, and then I need to match characters specified in the `$chars` variable only, case insensitive.

Comment: That will be interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$formula = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX';
$chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';

$serials = array(
    '9876-345-ABC',
    '7856Y-YURYW-00UEW-YUI23-YYYYY',
    '0934Y-R6834-27495-89999-11123'
);

foreach($serials as $serial) {
    $str  = str_replace(str_split($chars), 'X', $serial);
    echo $str == $formula ? "yes" : "no";
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is an interesting approach!

Comment: @SolomonClosson at least, fast :)

Comment: Would probably need to do case insensitive here though...  So `A` should match `A` and `a`.

Comment: you can make formula uppercase

Comment: Glad to help! I agree with your opinion :)

Comment: This is by far the best answer.  Not my original thought, but to get away from preg_match is a PLUS, and didn't think of it this way.  I have to accept this as my answer, or else I won't feel right in the morning.  Thank You all very very much!

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not the best one, but give it a shot and comment

**Assumption** :- `formula` contains only `X's`

```
$formula = 'XXX-XX-XXX-X-XXXXX';
$parts = split("\-", $formula);

$chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
$reg = '';

foreach ($parts as $x) {
    $reg = $reg . "" . '[' . "" . $chars . "" . ']{' . "" . strlen($x) . "" . "}" . "" . "-";
}

$reg = substr_replace($reg, '', -1);

$serials = array(
    '9876-345-ABC',
    '7856Y-YUR-00W-YUI23-YYY',
    '0934Y-R6834-27495-89999-11123',
    'XXX-XX-XXX-X-XXXXX'
);

$reg = '/^' . "" . $reg . "" . '$/';;

foreach($serials as $serial) {
    if(preg_match($reg, $serial) != 0) {
        echo $serial;
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/YYUWcP)**

Comment: Thank you for this.  Exactly what I was asking for!

Comment: @SolomonClosson glad it helped..don't forget to accept..:)

Comment: Thanks!  You totally ROCK!  I love both yours and @splash58, but I can only choose 1 answer :(

Comment: @SolomonClosson No problem..I am happy to deliver a `regex` based solution for which I was here

Answer (score 0):

You could go for (in `multiline mode`):

```
^(?:[0-9A-Z]{3,5}-?){3,5}$
# match the start of the line
# open a non-capturing group (?:
# look for a digit (0-9) or an uppercase letter (A-Z)
# ... between 3-5 times
# make the dash optional -?
# and repeat the non-capturing group 3-5 times
# $ makes sure this is the end of the string
```

As the wonderful [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) does not seem to work at the moment, here a non graphical example of the regex. It will match the ones with an asterisk at the end:

```
9876-345-ABC *
7856Y-YURYW-00UEW-YUI23-YYYYY *
0934Y-R6834-27495-89999-11123 *
this-one-not
this one neither
```

Translated to `PHP`, this would be:

```
$regex = '~^(?:[0-9A-Z]{3,5}-?){3,5}$~';
if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
    echo "This is a valid serial";
}
```

Comment: huh?  What did you post?  I'm confused by your answer.

Comment: @SolomonClosson: A regex to validate your serials. Unfortunately, the regex101.com engine does not seem to work at the moment.

Comment: @SolomonClosson: See the updated answer with `PHP` code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, not sure if what you posted will do the following?   
I need to match the pattern value of whatever $formula is, and $formula can be anything. But $formula is always using X chars as a placeholder and hyphens - as separators, and then I need to match characters specified in the $chars variable only, case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it this way, it will use "{}" on successive X.

```
/**
* $formula = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX';
* $chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
* $serials = array(
*    '9876-345-ABC',
*    '7856Y-YURYW-00UEW-YUI23-YYYYY',
*    '0934Y-R6834-27495-89999-11123'
* );
*/
function checkThisFormula($formula, $chars, array $serials) {
    $formulaLength = strlen($formula);
    $regex = "";
    $charsRegex = "[".$chars."]";
    $lastIsX = false;
    $nbX = 0;
    // let's construct the regex from formula
    for($i = 0; $i < $formulaLength; $i++) {
        if($formula[$i] === 'X') {
            // let's count how many X we see before writing
            $nbX++;
            $lastIsX = true;
        } else {
            if($lastIsX) {
                // end of successive Xs
                $regex .= "[".$chars."]";
                if($nbX > 1) {
                    $regex .= "{".$nbX."}";
                }
                // reinit X count
                $lastIsX = false;
                $nbX = 0;
            }
            // have to be this exact char
            $regex .= '\\'.$formula[$i];
        }
    }
    if($lastIsX) {
        // if the last char is an X, have to write it too !
        $regex .= "[".$chars."]";
        if($nbX > 1) {
            $regex .= "{".$nbX."}";
        }
    }
    // let's make the regex with flag for case insensitive
    $regex = "#".$regex."#i";
    $result = array();
    // let's loop on every serial to test it
    foreach($serials as $serial) {
        $result[$serial] = preg_match($regex, $serial);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

output :

```
Array
(
    [9876-345-ABC] => 0
    [7856Y-YURYW-00UEW-YUI23-YYYYY] => 1
    [0934Y-R6834-27495-89999-11123] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way would do something like that:

```
foreach($serials as $serial)
{
    if(preg_match("/([$chars]{5}-){4}[$chars]{5}/", $serial) == 1)
        echo 'found - '.$serial.'<br>';
}
```

Result would be:

```
found - 7856Y-YURYW-00UEW-YUI23-YYYYY
found - 0934Y-R6834-27495-89999-11123
```

I hope that's what you want to do.

Comment: Unfortunately, `$formula` may be anything.

Comment: Oh I see... so I guess there's no option to avoid ungainly code includes loops.